# Передача данных между скриптами С# Unity;

Tags: c#, unity3d, скрипт

Есть скрипт в котором я получаю координаты с сайта и преобразую их в список разделяя по символу ";".

```
    IEnumerator QuestFunc(WWW www)
{
    yield return www;
    CoorList(www.text);
    string otvet = www.text;
    string[] questt = otvet.Split(new string[] { ";" }, System.StringSplitOptions.None);
    var list = questt.ToList();
    a_Dropdown.options.Clear();
    a_Dropdown.AddOptions(list);
}
```

И есть скрипт в котором мне нужно получить этот список "list", как это сделать?

Comment: Через то же поле options? Как-то так `a_Dropdown.options.Select(x => x.text).ToList()`.

Comment: Этого DropDown не должно быть) Я через него проверял выгрузились ли координаты) Вообще можно оставить его за сценой и попробовать так, но уже костыль какой-то :(

Comment: Зависит от того что вы хотите сделать и когда вам этот список понадобится, какого он объёма и тд. Можете хранить в статическом поле, можете сохранять в файл. Если вы пользуетесь DI-контейнером, то можно внедрить его как зависимость.

Comment: Я делаю AR приложение и мне нужно добавить объекты по координатам, выше написал откуда, список понадобится после загрузки сцены, объем небольшой.

Comment: Самое простое - заведите публичное статическое свойство, к нему сможете обратититься из любого места кода по названию класса: `public static List<string> MyList { get; private set; }`. Только не злоупотребляйте статикой, она убила не один проект на юнити.

Answer (score 0):

Для передачи данных между сриптами можно использовать разные способы, к примеру:

Это скрипт на первом объекте:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Obj1 : MonoBehaviour
{

    int i;
    void Start()
    {
        i = 1;
    }
}
```

А вот на втором:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Obj2 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Object1;
    int Obj1_i;
    void Start()
    {
        Obj1_i = Object1.GetComponent<HingeJoint>().i;
    }
}
```

Вот ссылка на документацию:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html

Comment: Если хочешь получить list, то просто поменяй тип переменной.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Если этот ответ тебе помог, то поставь пожалуйста галочку:)